# Core of divergence form operator with unbounded coefficient

Tags: elliptic-pde, ap.analysis-of-pdes, fa.functional-analysis, unbounded-operators

Consider the unbounded operator $L$ on $L^2(\mathbb{R^d})$ to be the self-adjoint extension of 
$$Lf := \nabla \cdot \left(a(x) \nabla f(x) \right)$$ on $C^2_c(\mathbb{R^d})$.

I also assume that $a(x) > 0$ for all $x$ and $a(x)$ is differentiable.  However, I make no assumptions on the boundedness of $a$.

Does this operator have a core?  If so, can it be identified explicitly?

Thanks.

Comment: I don't think your operator is defined on $C^2_c$ without assuming more on $a$ like differentiability. Writing down the core for the quadratic form $q(f) = \int a(x) |\nabla f(x)|^2 dx is easy, since it's all $f$ such that $a^{1/2} |\nabla f| \in L^2(\mathbb{R}^d)$. Something similar works for $L$ (it's the obvious condition of everything being defined, so $a \nabla f$ being in $H^1$.

Comment: I can't delete the previous comment for some reasons. Here's the scrambled part.

since it's all $f$ such that $a^{1/2} |\nabla f| \in L^2(\mathbb{R}^d)$.

Something similar works for $L$. It should just be the $f$ such that $a \nabla f \in H^1$.

Comment: Yes, you're right,  $a(x)$ should be differentiable. I'll edit the question.  Another question:  So if a set C is a core for the Dirichlet form wouldn't this imply C is a core for L?  

Comment: What's a core? A reference would suffice.

Comment: Let $L$ be a closed operator on $L^2(D)$.  Then $\mathcal{D} \subset D(L)$ is said to be a core of $L$ if $\mathcal{D}$ is dense in $D(L)$ with respect to the graph norm  $||u||_{L^2} + ||Au||_{L^2}$.   Ethier and Kurtz is a good reference and contains various sufficient condition for a set of functions to be a core.

Comment: @RadonNikodym. I have two problems with your question: 

1) you write "THE self-adjoint extension of..". Is it clear that under your quite general assumptions you have just one selfadjoint extension (i.e. that L is essentially selfadjoint on $C_c^2$) ?

2) Of course any selfadjoint extension has its domain as a core. So what do you ask for exactly? Do you want to know if $C_c^2$ itself is a core? Or do you look for a core having specific properties?  